# Rename Reports by filename

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script that renames reports and puts them in a folder.

The Report names have to be changed to the right date (the date must be in the filename).

For example I have a report named "Report_2015_02"/ I have to subtract one month from the file name - **not the system time**.

The new report name in this case needs to be "Report_2015_01"

But at the moment I'm using systemtime, so the Reportname would be "Report_2017_02" because Systemtime (2017_03) minus one month is 2017_02...

**Q:** How to I use the date of the filename instead of the systemtime?

Here's my code:

```
#today's date (year-month-day)
$todaydate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd

#arrays  (today => systemtime)
$todaydate = $todaydate.Split('-')
$todaydate[0] #year
$todaydate[1] #month
$todaydate[2] #day

#arrays yesterday (systemtime - one day)
$yesterdaysdate = Get-Date((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$yesterdaysdate = $yesterdaysdate.Split('-')
$yesterdaysdate[0] #year
$yesterdaysdate[1] #month
$yesterdaysdate[2] #day

#arrays yesterday (systemtime - one day)
$lastmonth = Get-Date((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)) -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$lastmonth = $lastmonth.Split('-')
$lastmonth[0] #year
$lastmonth[1] #month
$lastmonth[2] #day

#Example 1:  Filename "Report_Telephone_yyyy-mm" => in this case "Report_Telephone_2016-12"
#it renames the file -> minus one month, so the name must be "Report_Telephone_2016-11"
$filename='Report_Telephone_'+ $lastmonth[0]+'-'+ $lastmonth[1] + '.xlsx'

write-host $filename
rename-item 'c:\Reporting\Report_Telephone_' + $todaydate[0] +'-' + $todaydate[1] + '.xlsx' -NewName $filename

$sourcepath='C:\Reporting\'+ $filename
write-host $sourcepath
$destinationpath='C:\Reporting\'+ $lastmonth[0]+'\'+ $lastmonth[1]
write-host $destinationpath
if(test-path $destinationpath)
{

} 
else 
{
     mkdir $destinationpath
}
move-item -path $sourcepath -destination $destinationpath



#Example 2:  Filename "Report_Outlook_yyyy-mm-dd" => in this case "Report_Outlook_2016-12-14"
#it renames the file -> minus one day, so the name must be "Report_Outlook_2016-12-13"

$filename='Report_Outlook_'+ $lastmonth[0]+'-'+ $lastmonth[1] + '.xlsx'

write-host $filename
rename-item 'c:\Reporting\Report_Outlook_' + $todaydate[0] +'-' + $todaydate[1] + '.xlsx' -NewName $filename

$sourcepath='C:\Reporting\'+ $filename
write-host $sourcepath
$destinationpath='C:\Reporting\'+ $yesterdaysdate[0]+'\'+ $yesterdaysdate[1]
write-host $destinationpath
if(test-path $destinationpath)
{

} 
else 
{
   mkdir $destinationpath
}
move-item -path $sourcepath -destination $destinationpath



#that is just for generating log-files
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$sourcepath\Protokoll_$todaydate.xls", $output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple *regex* to grab the month, *cast* it to an integer, *substract* 1 and finally *format* it as a string with two decimals:

```
$fileName = 'Report_2015_02' # Probably want to use Get-ChildItem here...
$fileMonth = [int][regex]::Match($fileName, '\w+_\d+_(\d+)').Groups[1].Value
$fileMonth = "{0:D2}" -f ($fileMonth - 1)
```